# ZMQ (jzmq) - what is the purpose of the ZThread?

Tags: thread-safety, zeromq, jzmq

I am using `jzmq` package for my project to communicate over network. I am using `DEALER ROUTER` pair. I have read that the socket with `DEALER` and `ROUTER` type **is not thread safe**. So I can not send or receive from the same socket on 2 different threads.

**My questions are**:
1 ) What is the purpose of the **`ZThread`** class in the jzmq package?

2 ) Does it handle this thread unsafety?

3 ) Can I send and receive from the same socket if using it from a parent thread and its child `ZThread`?

4 ) Also what is the difference between `Attached` and `AdetachedRunnable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fact #0: ZeroMQ was never thread-safe ( had Zero sharing Zen )

In spite of the most recent efforts ( published in late 2017 on 4.2+ total re-design efforts towards removing this known initial principle ), ZeroMQ education materials present wherever possible and also explain why there is a bad habit to try to share toys in [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) design practice.

---

### Ad 2 )

Even if one gets some API-baked promise, always first benchmark the performance, if one will ever want to pay the costs of lost performance for such ex-post sharing doctrine. As noted about the ZeroMQ native API, there is principally nothing to be shared ( with one exception, which sometimes may make sense, the global Context()-instance ). Threads may "borrow" the IO-socket instantiations from such a global Context()-instance, but never share socket-instances, as the results are not guaranteed inside and under the ZeroMQ native API and so will not be any better even if promised so "above" any kind of higher level API.

---

### Ad 3 ) No,

as per 2 ), never share sockets, there is no reason to try to do that. If managing resources ( and threads are first-class citizen among resources ), better create a private, point to point `PAIR/PAIR` or `PUSH/PULL` ( even in tandem of simplex pipes ) over `{ inproc:// | ipc:// }`-transport-class ( where `inproc://` can for performance motivated cases even use another "co-locally-isolated" private `Context(0)`-instance, having indeed zero IO-threads at all ) and enjoy the due separation of concerns with minimum adverse effects on principally lost thread-safety ( if not doing so ) and performance.

### Ad 1 + 4 )

> *( CZMQ/3.0.1 API docs )* **`zthread`** - working with system threads (deprecated)
>   ...
>   The `zthread` class wraps OS thread creation. It creates detached threads that look like normal OS threads, or attached threads that share the caller's ØMQ context, and get an `inproc` pipe to talk back to the parent thread. Detached threads create their own ØMQ contexts as needed. NOTE: this class is deprecated in favor of `zactor`.

One may better check the version creeps among native API used, the binding / wrapper version and documentation.

Yet, Zero sharing Zen may lead your steps ( if selected language binding permits one to remain free in design decisions - reading the original design motivations always helps understand the performance and safety insights from The Original ).